# AWS Cloudformation create policy stuck

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I work with AWS CloudFormation a lot, but I cannot see why this policy creation gets stuck (every time it hangs on `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS` with no error message). I singled out the one component which gets stuck and tried to deploy that on its own, but it simply does not get created and I cannot see what is wrong with it. The IAM policy is an inline policy on a group with put permissions on a firehose resource, as seen below:

```yaml
Resources:
  MyPolicy:
    Properties:
      Groups:
        - MyGroup
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - firehose:PutRecord
            Effect: Allow
            Resource:
              - arn:aws:firehose:eu-central-1:123456789:deliverystream/my-firehose
        Version: '2012-10-17'
      PolicyName: my-firehose-policy
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
```

Answer (score 3):

Accidently answered my own question. I already created a lot of inline policies, which exceeded the maximum number of characters for inline policies under a certain group. This error message was not immediately clear.

```
Maximum policy size of 5120 bytes exceeded for group administrator
```

[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_iam-limits.html)

Comment: Did you find a workaround? I found [other persons](https://medium.com/@fastup/aws-iam-policy-too-long-980602bf8d05) having the same problem but not real solutions except "minifying" the policy

Comment: See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-increase-policy-size/